# MongoDB error - Command failed with error 352: 'Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert'

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

**Exception message** - 'Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see [https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal'](https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal%27) on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see [https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal"](https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal%22), "code" : 352, "codeName" : "UnsupportedOpQueryCommand" }

**Dependency** -

```
        <!-- mongodb java driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Properties**

```
info.mongo.host=localhost
info.mongo.port=27017
info.mongo.dbname=testing
```

**Code** -

```
private static MongoClient mongo;
DBCollection dbCollection = mongo.getDB(dbName)).getCollection(collectionName);
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
document.put("field", "test field");
dbCollection.insert(document);
```

Can anyone please come up with a favor regarding this issue?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74077700/mongoerror-unsupported-op-query-command-insert/74078475#74078475

Comment: Guidance for what to do ("_The client driver may require an upgrade_") along with a link to a page containing more details are provided in the error message that you've shared directly. What additional assistance are you looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoError: Unsupported OP\_QUERY command: insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74077700/mongoerror-unsupported-op-query-command-insert)