# Add MongoDB in Redash Error: Unsupported OP_QUERY command

Tags: mongodb, docker, redash

When adding a new Data Source to a fresh Redash installation (I installed it in Docker via their install script), I get the following Error when testing the Connection:

```
Connection Test Failed:
Unsupported OP_QUERY command: connectionStatus. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal
```

[image]

My connection String is the one exported from MongoDB Compass:

```
mongodb://user:pass@host:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT
```

I try to connect to the existing `matches` database.

I also cannot find any Errors regarding this issue in the logs of the ruinning Containers.
Is this Error caused by a bad connection String or is this a Bug in Redash and how do I solve this?

Comment: not exactly the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74077700/mongoerror-unsupported-op-query-command-insert/74078475#74078475, but the same underlying reason, you use a too new server with too old driver

Comment: Okay, I didn't find any possibility to upgrade the driver through npm. Downgrading the MongoDB Server to v.5.0 made it work,