# Error [MongoError]: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

I cannot work anymore on my project KeystoneJS.

I am getting this error:

```
Error searching database for update 0.0.1-admins:
Error [MongoError]: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: find. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal
```

I am not sure if I have to downgrade or upgrade my Mongodb driver or Mongoose.

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Update the driver as the red notice in the link recommends. Mongoose should have its own compatibility matrix that you'll have to follow as well

Comment: My reading of the Mongo docs (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#legacy-opcodes-removed) is that you either need to downgrade your DB _or_ upgrade your driver...? It's not super clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoError: Unsupported OP\_QUERY command: insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74077700/mongoerror-unsupported-op-query-command-insert)

Comment: What is the command that I have to run to do that?

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#legacy-opcodes-removed

I had run `npm install mongodb` and I without results.

Upgrade Drivers
To avoid disruption due to the removal of these opcodes, upgrade your driver to the latest version.