# Mongodb 6.0 error: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: listCollections. The client driver may require upgrade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dbmigrate

We are upgrading Node and Mongodb version for our applications. We have upgraded

```
Mongodb: 6.0.8
NodeJs Mongo Driver: 6.0.0
NodeJs: 18.17.0
db-migrate: 0.11.14
```

in migrations file we are declaring MongoClient like this

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

below error we are getting while running the migrations for creating the table and dbs.
Error: **[Error] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: ifError got unwanted exception: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: listCollections. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see** https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal
**at module.exports (/node_modules/db-migrate/lib/commands/up.js:29:16)**

We were using mongodb 3.x and Nodejs 14.x versions, when we have upgraded to mongodb 6.x and Nodejs 18.x, we are getting this unsupported OP_QUERY error, not able find the solution because lack of documentation.

**What should be the Node driver version with below configuration?**

```
Mongodb: 6.0.8
NodeJs Mongo Driver: 6.0.0
NodeJs: 18.17.0
```

Comment: the error says what to do, you should upgrade node driver. A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74077700/mongoerror-unsupported-op-query-command-insert/74078475#74078475

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoError: Unsupported OP\_QUERY command: insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74077700/mongoerror-unsupported-op-query-command-insert)

Comment: I have already on latest stable version of nodejs and mongodb.

Comment: it's not about node, but about node mongo driver

Comment: latest node mongo driver is mongodb@6.1, and i have mongodb@6.0.8, does this make any difference?

Comment: If you still have this error, I would vote that you still use the old driver, I'm not a node developer, so can't help more on this, but I would recommend double check the driver version